# Triggering a GKE CronJob workload from cloud composer

Tags: python, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have a google cloud composer environment running. In this composer I want to orchestrate the execution of a GKE CronJob workload, and a google dataflow job. For the dataflow job part, I came to run it, now I'm having some issue with the GKE workload.

While researching, I came to find `GKEStartPodOperator` which I used to start the pod in GKE. The thing is the pod got created, but it doesn't run

The code I used

```
kubernetes_min_pod = GKEStartPodOperator(
    # The ID specified for the task.
    task_id="task-id",
    # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
    name="name-cronjob",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    location=CLUSTER_REGION,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
    # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
    cmds=["python", "/app/src/main.py"],
    arguments=["/app/config.json"],
    # The namespace to run within Kubernetes, default namespace is
    # `default`.
    namespace="production",
    # Docker image specified. Defaults to hub.docker.com, but any fully
    # qualified URLs will point to a custom repository. Supports private
    # gcr.io images if the Composer Environment is under the same
    # project-id as the gcr.io images and the service account that Composer
    # uses has permission to access the Google Container Registry
    # (the default service account has permission)
    image="eu.gcr.io/project_id/app_image:latest",
)
```

My code source was based on [the google cloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/using-gke-operator#launch_workloads_in_the_cluster)

When I run the DAG, it runs successfully, but the pod is created without the app in the container gets triggered. The pod status is green, as there are no logs (the app is not executed)

The workload that I want to trigger is a cronJob that is hosted in a GKE cluster in my project.

Has anyone worked with this before

Comment: Can you run your CronJob manually? What is the version of the CronJob controller? How many jobs is your CronJob handling?

Comment: I can run the cronJob manually from the GKE cluster. 
For the CronJob controller, I guess it's managed by GKE, couldn't find where the version is. 
One job, that it runs a docker container

Comment: Okay, from what i have seen this Issue happens in GKE versions that are lower than 1.21+ You can try this command: to check your GKE version:  `gcloud container get-server-config --flatten="channels" --filter="channels.channel=RAPID"  --zone=YOUR_ZONE   --format="yaml(channels.channel,channels.defaultVersion)"`.
Also if your version is higher than the 1.21+ The problem could be that you use the default implementation and you need to set the [CronJob ControllerV2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#new-controller) to false.

Comment: Thank you @JoseGutierrezPaliza for you reply, I checked the version, and indeed it's `1.22.8-gke.200` . Now I want to set `CronJobControllerV2` to test it, but I don't know how to do it. I wanted to try `kubelet parameters add --feature-gates=CronJobControllerV2=false=false` but what I find is GKE doesn't allow modifying the core using kubelet (please accept my apologies as I'm kind of new to GKE)